# Calculating CRC16 in Python for modbus

Tags: python, python-2.x, crc, modbus

Firstly, sorry! I am a beginner...

I got the following byte sequence on a modbus: "01 04 08 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 **f8 0c**". The CRC on bold on this byte sequence is correct. However, to check/create the CRC I have to follow the device especs that states:

*The error checking must be done using a 16 bit CRC implemented as two 8 bit bytes. The CRC is appended to the frame as the last field. The low order byte of the CRC is appended first, followed by the high order byte. Thus, the CRC high order byte is the last byte to be sent in the frame. The polynomial value used to generate the CRC must be 0xA001.*

Now, how can I check the CRC using crcmod?
My code is:

```
import crcmod
crc16 = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x1A001, rev=True, initCrc=0xFFFF, xorOut=0x0000)
print crc16("0104080000000900000000".decode("hex"))
```

I tried everything but I can't get the "f8 0C" that is correct on the byte sequence...

Comment: You can use pre-computed crc as mentioned here https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001537/references/r_python_crc16_modbus.htm. it will save computation power. This one should also work https://github.com/Kalebu/crc16-modbus-in-Python

Comment: To convert the string of hex characters to a byte sequence use `codecs.decode("0104080000000900000000", "hex")`

Comment: Added the `[python-2.x]` tag, as `'00'.decode('hex')` is not valid in 3.x. The modern spelling is `bytes.fromhex('00')`.

Comment: "I tried everything but I can't get the "f8 0C" that is correct on the byte sequence..." What result *do* you get? What does the documentation say about how to use `crcmod.mkCrcFun`? When you wrote `0x1A001, rev=True, initCrc=0xFFFF, xorOut=0x0000`, how did you choose those values, and how does that relate to your problem specification?

Comment: What value do you get?  0x0CF8 is decimal 3320.  That's what I expect you'll print.

Comment: Let explain further... The byte sequence you see has been captured from a RS485 serial interface of a power meter via HAN - Home Area Network interface. As you can see, it is "01 04 08 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 f8 0c" where the f8 0c is the CRC that should be reverted, so 0c f8. What I want is to use the crcmod to produce the same CRC that is 0x0cf8 in hex or 3320 in decimal. As the documentation says the polynomial value used to generate the CRC must be 0xA001.

I am a beginner on this... How should I enter the value into my crc_func to obtain the same CRC on this sequence?

Comment: I answered your question six hours before that comment.

Answer (score 2):

A simple implementation of the MODBUS CRC without any additional lib:

```
def modbusCrc(msg:str) -> int:
    crc = 0xFFFF
    for n in range(len(msg)):
        crc ^= msg[n]
        for i in range(8):
            if crc & 1:
                crc >>= 1
                crc ^= 0xA001
            else:
                crc >>= 1
    return crc

msg = bytes.fromhex("0104080000000900000000")
crc = modbusCrc(msg)
print("0x%04X"%(crc))            

ba = crc.to_bytes(2, byteorder='little')
print("%02X %02X"%(ba[0], ba[1]))
```

The output is:

```
0x0CF8
F8 0C
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `0x18005` instead of `0x1A001`.

Comment: I have tried but it does not work or I am missing something. Can you share the code you used? By other hand, the document from the power meter clearly states to use 0xA001.

Comment: It worked for me. I used exactly the code in your question, with `0x18005`. The result was 3320.

Comment: You right! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modbus shortcut, if not diving into the CRC detail

```
from pymodbus.utilities import computeCRC
```

Comment: This doesn't exist. Not sure if it did in the past, but when I asked chatgpt, this is what it also said. But most recent version of pymodbus at least does not have this