# How to send more bytes via serial.write()

Tags: python, pyserial, serial-communication

I wanted to control an optical device (stepper motor) via serial connection and I'm using the `serial` package to send the required bytes. For example, to move the stepper motor to the right I use the following code and of course, it works!

```
with serial.Serial(port='COM4', baudrate=115200) as ser:
        ser.write('rigt'.encode('utf-8'))
        ser.close()
```

But since I'm using a command which is longer than one byte, it doesn't work. With the following link, you can see the code structure of them. For example, the command `movr` requires more bytes... I hope this question is not to specific and appreciate any help!

[Communication Protocol Commands](https://doc.xisupport.com/en/8smc4-usb/8SMCn-USB/Programming/Communication_protocol_specification.html#crc-calculation)

Comment: According to the linked document, there's a Python example application provided. There's also annanswer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74505556/2836621 about calculating the CRC.

Comment: I tried this but I am not really sure what should I do... sorry but can you give me a short example e.g. the move command?